# HTML Anchors: move focus without jumping

Tags: html, accessibility, lightbox

I have some anchors within a page for accessibility. It's basically a long list of values on the left, each one of which opens a div on the right.

To avoid the need for a keyboard user to tab through all the remaining left hand side links, using an anchor moves focus to the appropriate elements on the right.  However the screen jumps "down" so the target anchor is on the top.

This is normally fine, however I have the page open in a lightbox (via jQuery). So if the target is in the middle of the lightbox, the parent page jumps--putting half the box out of site.

You cannot get it back, as the main page has no scrollbars.  These were removed in the box implementation because otherwise users of mousewheels were getting the box annoyingly scroll out of view if they used the wheel.

Comment: You'll probably need to override default anchor behavior with JS. Do you have jQuery available?

Comment: yes, i have jQuery, and i have found lots of answers about using prevent default.  However i think this actually prevents the focus from moving to the anchor?  

I can see that it is possible with dynamic content, that the page might need to scroll to bring the focused area into the viewport, however i want the colorbox to scroll, not the parent page.

I am using jackmoore colorbox/jquery at the moment.